# iPad version of website not sitting inline

Tags: html, css

The iPad version of my website doesn't sit inline. The image seems to sit beneath the text and the same applies when you reduce the website window on a computer.

http://www.lauradawaf.co.uk/daisy-whitney-make-up-artist#

Is there any way to stop this being the case?

**HTML**

```
<div id="content" class="clearfix">

<div class="leftCol noborder">Daisy Whitney</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="leftCol">Testing where this shows up. Testing where this shows up. Testing where this shows up. Testing where this shows up.</div>

<ul id="projectBreakdown" class="rightCol gallery clearfix">
<li class="large"><img src="http://www.lauradawaf.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/test.jpg" style="display: inline-block" ></li>
<li class="large"><img src="http://www.lauradawaf.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/test.jpg" style="display: inline-block" ></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Individual Projects
------------------------------------------------------------ */  
#content {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 960px;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    font-size: 0;
}

.leftCol {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.leftCol.noborder {
    border-top: none;
    padding-top: 3px;
}

#projectBreakdown {
float: left;
list-style: none;
width: 100%;
max-width: 960px;
min-width: 720px;
padding: 5px 0 30px 0;
}

.rightCol {
position: relative;
}

#projectBreakdown li.large, #projectBreakdown li.large img {
width: 100%;
max-width: 940px;
min-width: 700px;
}

#projectBreakdown li {
float: left;
margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your trying to dynamically size the photos while keeping the text on the left fixed all the while keeping a minimum 960px width? CSS still has trouble accomplishing exactly what you want. I agree with refhat that you should look into CSS media queries to properly display webpages on and iPad and smaller displays.

Regarless, here's some code for you to consider. I took some major liberties with both the html and css code. And... I used css tables.

[HTML and CSS code sandbox](http://cssdesk.com/nSsAD)

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing this to work in an ipad? There is no specific CSS for  ipad. The view port meta tag is missing too:

Add this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;" />
```

And then write CSS specific for devices using media queries.